# S3 Bucket Event Suffix .zip not taking effect

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Using the S3 Management Console I have created an S3 bucket.  In the properties I have added an event to alert on "All Object Create Events" with prefix "incomingData" and suffix ".zip".  The event alert will be sent to a SQS queue.

Whenever I upload a .txt or .csv file into folder "incomingData"an event alert is generated.  It is not applying the suffix condition.  Not sure if this is a restriction on the free tier service? Has anyone encountered this behavior?

[image: Event configuration screen-shot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AWS Free Tier is a billing discount. It has zero impact on services.

Please note that Prefixes should **not** start with a slash (`/`). If the prefix is a directory, it should be `incomingData/`.

To reproduce your situation, I did the following:

- Created an **Amazon S3 bucket**
- Created an **Amazon SQS queue** and added an access policy based on [Configuring Amazon S3 event notifications - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html)
- Configured an **Amazon S3 event** on the bucket per your picture (using a prefix of `incomingData/`)
- The Amazon SQS queue received a `s3:TestEvent` confirming that the connection was successful

I then ran some tests:

- Upload `foo.zip` to the root of the bucket: **No message received**
- Upload `foo.zip` to `incomingData/foo.zip`: **Message received**
- Upload `foo.txt` to `incomingData/foo.txt`: **No message received**

Therefore, I was **unable to reproduce your situation**.

I suggest you try correcting the `Prefix` and test it again.